# Partiall works: Trying to get AsyncStorage object using componentDidMount in React Native

Tags: react-native, components, asyncstorage

Problem is:
If there is user, App.js redirects to MainPage and I can get **AsyncStorage Object**

But if there is no user it redirects to Login Page and console shows that *Object* is empty (ok, because if no user I am not setting Object), and when it's logged in,  App.js sets item (shown in console) and redirects to MainPage (but this in case my AsyncStorage shows just {})

**MainPage**

```
async componentDidMount() {
  myArray = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userInfo');
  const d = JSON.parse(myArray);
  console.log('dddddddddddd:',d)
  this.setState({userInfa: d})
}
```

**my console**
[image]

**App.js**

```
componentDidMount() {
 this.authListener();
}
authListener() {
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
   if (user) {
     this.setState({ user });
     const userInfo = {
       username: user.displayName,
       emailVerified: user.emailVerified,
       photoURL: user.photoURL,
       userId: user.uid
     }
     AsyncStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(userInfo));
     console.log('userInfo:::::::AAAAAppp', userInfo)
    } else {
     this.setState({ user: null });
   }
  });
  }
```

> I am new user in react native, and actually I don't understand **componenDidMount()**. Hope you will help

Answer (score 0):

With the amount of information available, there could be two issues, either your AsyncStorage is not setting the item in the local storage ( you are logging userInfo which is local const, how do you know if AsyncStorage is setting it ) or you are fetching it before it's storing it in the local storage ( because I see you aren't using async await while storing it )

Comment: So I need to use async/await in my App.js storing?

Comment: Yes. Make sure you are setting the it in the local storage.

Comment: Use getItem in your App.js after your set it in the local storgae, get usrInfo and log it. Check if it is an empty object.

Comment: In the image above your logging the local constant. Log via Async.getItem after you have done Async.setItem